# Php files not loading on mac with apachectl started

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm all out of whack on my mac apache setup.  I ran a tutorial that suggested Brew before I realized Mojave already preinstalls apache.  Now no php files load

When I run `which httpd` I get this result:

```
/usr/local/bin/httpd
```

This command `ps -aef | grep httpd`
Produces this:

```
    0 69773     1   0 12:59PM ??         0:00.51 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
   70 75531 69773   0  5:00PM ??         0:00.01 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
   70 75532 69773   0  5:00PM ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
   70 75533 69773   0  5:00PM ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
   70 75534 69773   0  5:00PM ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
   70 75535 69773   0  5:00PM ??         0:00.02 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
   70 75537 69773   0  5:00PM ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
   70 75538 69773   0  5:00PM ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
   70 75539 69773   0  5:00PM ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -k start
  501 75680 89456   0  5:08PM ttys002    0:00.00 grep httpd
```

which indicates that my apache is running.  From questions on the similar issue I've seen it says that I need to uncomment the LoadModule for PHP however in my config there is no LoadModule for php.  Nothing in `httpd.conf` says anything about php.  I manually changed or added this:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule

#Stackoverflow answer
<FilesMatch .php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

But this line is nowhere to be found:

```
LoadModule **php7_module** libexec/apache2/**libphp7.so**
```

According to `php -v`
Php is loaded and running thou.

```
PHP 7.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul 19 2018 12:14:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.8, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

When I go to localhost it resolve.  However the php page that appears is just the code so it's not rendering the php page.

It appears the source of my httpd.conf is this:

```
/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf 

LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

I get an error

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 182 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/httpd/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so, 10): image not found
```

Comment: The `which` and `ps` commands return the same results on my machine. However, you should have a line like this in your `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` : `LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`

Comment: Adding this gives me this error:  httpd: Syntax error on line 182 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/httpd/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so, 10): image not found
My config is actually here usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf  Is there away I can change it back? I'm not even sure how it got that way.  @Yoric

Comment: You may try this command `sudo find /usr -name "libphp7.so`, and replace the path of the LoadModule accordingly into your httpd.conf

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to set up a web server on a Mac.  In most environs, getting Apache and PHP running takes very little effort, the Mac takes just enough time that I don't bother.  I suggest checking out Docker.  https://www.tecmint.com/install-apache-web-server-in-a-docker-container/

Comment: I actually was driving thinking I should go docker @user2182349

Comment: I use PHP on the Mac for syntax checking